# JAVASCRIPT: Trying to create a hasCallbackFor function on a custom event dispatcher

Tags: javascript, event-handling, event-listener

I'm working on an exercise right now creating a custom event dispatcher.

I am given a pile of test cases, and I'm stuck at creating a method on my event listener object called hasCallbackFor(name, callback). From what I can gather, the hasCallbackFor function is supposed to take a name of a key on the object i'm creating, and callback is a function that is located in an array at that key. It's supposed to check if that function exists. I'm absolutely lost on how to do this and feel like I've tried everything.

This is the test case for the hasCallbackFor function:

```
var shouldReturnFalseHasCallBackForIfMethodsNotAdded = function () {
    testObj = {};
    var scope = {
        executeSuccess: true
    }
    var testFunction = function () {
        if (this.executeSuccess) {
            success1 = true;
        }
    }
    EventDispatcher.mixin(testObj);
    testObj.addEventListener('test', testFunction, scope);
    testObj.dispatchEvent('test');
    assert(testObj.hasCallbackFor("test", testFunction), 'should have callback registered for test event');
    assert(!testObj.hasCallbackFor("test", function () {}), 'should have no callback');
    console.log('shouldReturnFalseHasCallBackForIfMethodsNotAdded: success')
}
```

This is my addEventListener function:

```
/**
 * @param {string} name
 * @param {function} callback
 * @param {Object} opt_scope
 */
addEventListener: function (name, callback, opt_scope) {
    if(!EventDispatcher.myObject[name]) {
        EventDispatcher.myObject[name] = [];
    }
    if(opt_scope) {
        var bound = callback.bind(opt_scope);
        EventDispatcher.myObject[name].push(bound);
    } else {
        EventDispatcher.myObject[name].push(callback);
    }
},
```

This is my dispatchEvent function:

```
/**
 * @param {string} name
 */
dispatchEvent: function (name) {
    EventDispatcher.myObject[name].forEach(function(value) {
       value();
    });
},
```

And for my hasCallbackFor function, I'm trying to use

```
/**
 * @param {string} name
 * @param {function} callback
 * @return {boolean}
 */
hasCallbackFor: function (name, callback) {
    return EventDispatcher.myObject[name].includes(callback);
},
```

This function fails the test case at the

```
 assert(testObj.hasCallbackFor("test", testFunction), 'should have callback registered for test event');
```

line, and I've officially run out of ideas why. I've been staring at this code for about 3 hours now and would appreciate any insight on this. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function name `testFunction` in this case is an *address* of the code.
Let consider a small example:

```
var arr = [];
var foo = function(e){return true;};
arr.push(foo);
console.log(arr.includes(foo));//true
var bar = foo.bind('something');
arr.push(bar);
arr.includes(bar);//true
arr.includes(foo.bind('something'));//false .bind creates a new function every time
//The worst case:
arr.push(function(e){return true;});//anonymous function is lost forever
console.log(arr.includes(function(e){return true;}));//false
```

Back to OP. So the issue is here:

```
var bound = callback.bind(opt_scope);//creates a new function with a new address
EventDispatcher.myObject[name].push(bound);
```

I offer two solutions:
**Return the function from `addEventListener`**

```
addEventListener: function (name, callback, opt_scope) {
    if(!EventDispatcher.observable[name]) {
        EventDispatcher.observable[name] = [];
    }
    if (opt_scope) {
        var bound = callback.bind(opt_scope);
        EventDispatcher.observable[name].push(bound);
        return bound;
    } else {
        EventDispatcher.observable[name].push(callback);
        return callback;
    }
}
```

and in `shouldReturnFalseHasCallBackForIfMethodsNotAdded` call the function like this:

```
var foo = testObj.addEventListener('test', testFunction, scope);
//  ^^^
testObj.dispatchEvent('test');
assert(testObj.hasCallbackFor("test", foo), 'should have callback registered for test event');
//                                    ^^^
```

**Bind the function in `shouldReturnFalseHasCallBackForIfMethodsNotAdded`** and do not send `scope` to `addEventListener`

```
//addEventListener is the same as in OP
var foo = testFunction.bind(scope);
testObj.addEventListener('test', foo, null);
testObj.dispatchEvent('test');
assert(testObj.hasCallbackFor("test", foo), 'should have callback registered for test event');
```

Both work.

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH for the help and detailed explanation! I knew it had something to do with the bound functions pointing to different things and just couldn't figure out how to solve it. Again, thank you!